# Is it possible to change an element in a queue?

Tags: c#, queue

Let say if I have a queue of integer (or any class T), can I change the value of the element in the queue?
More specifically, if I define the queue as follow:

```
Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
```

Can we change the value of its element similar to how we deal with an array? (if q were an array, we would be able to do something like this: `q[0]=1` to change its element). I just would like to simplify the scenario and use int as example, but my intention was trying to peek at the 1st item of a class T in a queue, do some calculations and update the queue for other programs to process. I do not want to dequeue it because it the sequence in the queue will then not be the same as the original. Hope what am trying to do make sense. Please advise.

Comment: Are the elements in the queue structs or classes? Also, may I ask why you want to change something in the queue?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail *why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: @BradChristie: I would like to use the queue to process the information. Information has to be performed according to a certain sequence. Each module will not have all the info and it would be nice if each module will update an element and at the end of the "assembly line", it will be processed totally.

Comment: @user1205746: You can't populate the queue based on the previous element's activity? Use it almost like how the print spooler tests if there is another page to print based on the most recent page's content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the item in the queue was a mutable type then you could change the value that the queue has as it's first item.  Without re-creating the queue, or performing a lot of enqueues/dequeues there is no way to change which item is at the front of the queue.

As an example of the first case, if you had a `Queue<MyClass>` with a definition of:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Queue<MyClass> queue = new Queue<MyClass>();
queue.Enqueue(new MyClass() { Value = "1" });
queue.Peek().Value = 2;
string value = queue.Peek().Value; // is 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Servy! So I can only the first element? We can probably also doing something like this: queue.ElementAt(i).Value = 2 as well?

Comment: @user1205746 You *can*, but you probably shouldn't.  If you need to be accessing something other than the first item chances are you're using the wrong data structure.  `Queue` is designed to give you the first item, or every item, but not the n-th item.

Comment: agreed. I had intention to use the queue for one thing and then stuff evolved leading to the idea of grand fathering something else in the queue which was not wise. I will keep both things separate. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly change an item in `Queue` (although you can use a workaround [as Tudor suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372114/41071)). But if you want to have a queue, you don't have to use `Queue`. Another possible type from .Net is [`LinkedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx). It allows you to add and remove things from both ends, which can be used in your scenario:

```
LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>();

// enqueue an item
list.AddLast(1);

// dequeue an item
var item = list.First.Value;
list.RemoveFirst();

// put item back to the front of the queue
list.AddFirst(item);
```

It seems you want to do this to process each item by several modules in sequence. But I'm not sure this is the right way to do this kind of work. A better way might be to have a queue between each two modules. A module would always take an item from its input queue, process it and then put it in its output queue.

One of the advantages of this approach is greater flexibility: a module can have different type on the output than on the input, which is not possible with the “one queue” approach (unless you resort to having a queue of `object`s, or something like that).

TPL Dataflow (new in .Net 4.5) uses this approach to improve performance through parallelization. It can do that, because each module can process items independently of other modules if you don't have a single central queue.

Comment: Linked list is what I am thinking of. I had 2 issues combined into 1 question. In the scenario where I need to change information on multiple modules, linked list is a solution. I will still need the queue for FIFO scenario. Thanks for your instructions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're storing a reference type like a class, any changes you make to it will be reflected in the Queue.  The output of the code below will be "2":

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Queue<MyClass> q = new Queue<MyClass>();
        q.Enqueue(new MyClass { Value = 1 });
        var i = q.Peek();
        i.Value++;
        i = q.Peek();
        Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple wrapper:

```
class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Queue<Wrapper<int>> q = new Queue<Wrapper<int>>();
    Wrapper<int> wr = new Wrapper<int> { Value = 1 };
    q.Enqueue(wr);

    Wrapper<int> wr1 = q.Peek();
    wr1.Value = 2;

    int value = q.Dequeue().Value;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Well, it can work for other items in the queue, because `Queue` implements `IEnumerable`. So you could do something like `q.ElementAt(10).Value = 42;`. But I certainly wouldn't recommend doing that (among other things because it would be slow).

Comment: @svick: Ah yes, good point. Anyway, I think his use case was only about the head of the queue.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give it a swirl. If it is too slow, then I will see if there is a way around it.

Comment: Thank you Tudor and Servy. Both your solutions are what I wanted but I only have the ability to mark 1 answer as "answer". Anyway, your help very much appreciated.

Comment: @user1205746 You can upvote any answer that you find helpful, even if you can't mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Queue<T> SetFirstTo<T>(this Queue<T> q, T value)
        {
            T[] array = q.ToArray();
            array[0] = value;
            return new Queue<T>(array);
        }
    }
```

Strictly this is not mutating the Queue so re-assignment required.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Queue()
        {
            var queue = new Queue<int>(new[]{1,2,3,4});
            queue = queue.SetFirstTo(9);
            Assert.AreEqual(queue.Peek(),9);
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

The simple answer is no. It's not part of the API of Queue object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

However anything is possible of course. You could write an extension method to do this,  but it would have to work with the API of the object and so dequeue / enqueue all items along with the change whilst preserving the order.

But if you want to do this, you are treating the Queue as a List, so why not use a List?

Comment: That's not the case. The operation in question is a combination of operations on the queue all of which are possible. There is just no single operation that has the required effect. Kind of like all programming.

Comment: BTW your link is wrong. You link to the old non-generic `Queue` that shouldn't be used. The question is talking about [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

Comment: I don't believe that's the implication - but rather the interpretation. However thanks for the down vote anyway.  Your own answer is to replace the queue with a new queue, which is effectively what this extension method will do, but in place.