# C# Stack Modify Top Element

Tags: c#, collections, stack

If I want to modify the top of the `Stack`, how would I do that?

I know you can use `Stack.Pop()` and then push back the modified value, but that seems inelegant.
Is there another way?

Example:

```cs
Stack<string> stringStack;
stringStack.Push("foo");
stringStack.Push("ba");
stringStack.Replace("bar"); //implementation
```

This seems it has a really obvious answer to it. Don't know why it's not implemented yet.

Comment: You can create an extension method for Stack. In that method, just Pop and Push the new value again.

Comment: You won't be able to escape the pop and push, its just the way stacks are implemented in .net. Good news is both operations are O(1) *if* it doesn't breach the capacity. To be very honest, if you need to make many mutations to the elements in your collection, an array or List<T> are much better suited as that would be a single O(1) operation vs 2 for the stack pop-push

Comment: Just to have it mentioned: As suggested in [this answer (related to `Queue`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372014/is-it-possible-to-change-an-element-in-a-queue#answer-12372088), it is possible to modify the top element when you have a stack of _reference types_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension method like this;

```cs
public static class StackExtensions
{
    public static void Replace<T>(this Stack<T> stack, T item)
    {
        stack.Pop();
        
        stack.Push(item);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this;

```cs
var stringStack = new Stack<string>();
stringStack.Push("foo");
stringStack.Push("ba");
stringStack.Replace("bar");

foreach (var item in stringStack)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Which will give you this output;

```
bar
foo
```